# How to migrate to Azure from IIS

Tags: windows, azure

Are there any tools or processes available for migrating the services which got deployed in `IIS` to `Windows Azure Cloud space`. Is there any way to take snapshot/image of a set of virtual directories and move it to Windows Azure?

-Mahender

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to run an IIS web site on Windows Azure (see http://davidpallmann.blogspot.com/2012/07/windows-azure-is-3-lane-highway-how-to.html for a comparison).

1. Windows Azure Web Sites
2. Cloud Services (Platform-as-a-Service) - Hosted Service
3. Virtual Machines (Infrastructure-as-a-Service)

If your requirement is to copy files up and be done with it, option 1 (WAWS) and option 3 (Virtual Machines) allow that. You can upload files by FTP for WAWS, and through a remote desktop connection for VMs. However, note that WAWS does not support multiple virtual directories or any kind of custom IIS configuration. And with Virtual Machines, you have the responsibility of managing your VMs yourself.

I recommend going through the hands-on labs in the Windows Azure Training Kit (downloadable from azure.com) to see what's involved in setting up web sites using these different approaches to determine which is the best fit for you.